# Audio noise listener while webRTC on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, webrtc

I use webRTC in my application for audio calling, now there is a need to listen to the noise level in order to determine whether the call participant is speaking or not and inform the server about it. As far as I know, app cannot use a microphone for two different tasks at the same time.
How can I implement this functionality?